# Changing listview adapter back and forth?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

When the user first loads the listview, it pulls the date column from an sqlitedb and populates the list. When they click on a date, I put that date in a variable. I then want to display a list of items from an array. And then when they click one of those items, it again pulls data from an sqlitedb and populates.

So initial listview:
12-2010
01-2011
03-2011
04-2011

click on any date, set mDate = clicked item
change listview to display what's in an array, then it's looking look

Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
Option 4

click on an option, set mOption = clicked item
change listview to pull data based on mOption from the db.

I know how to get the listview to pull info from each of these sources, what I'm not clear on, is the best way to handle these adapter switches. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this data fixed? i.e., you have three sets of static data during the life of the application or the database may change at any moment?

Comment: I'm having the same question: whether or not it's better to update a listadapter with two different sets of data vs having two adapters. There's also the option to have both sets of data in a custom listview adapter and having the adapter have a switch function (do refresh/invalidate/whatever they call it in Android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two options.  You can have multiple `ListView` that each have their own adapter that you switch between or you can have multiple adapters that you just set to the `ListView`.  Personally I would go with option 1 so you can put the `ListView`s in a `ViewSwitcher` and animate the transitions.

Answer (score 0):

If data may change at any moment, the cheapest and most reusable way I believe would be to use:

```
public void updateContents (ListView lv, List<String> list) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = lv.getAdapter();
    myAdapter.clear();
    myAdapter.AddAll (list);
    lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
```

But, this only works in android 4.0 or later. 2.3 and lower does NOT support ArrayAdapter.AddAll(object);